# Loops and user input validation in java, again

Tags: java, loops, validation, intellij-idea

So, I think about two days back I asked a question about input validation, and how to loop programs until the user gave a valid input..

So I made a calculator and I wanted to loop every step of the program so that if the user didn't put a `double` (69, 42.0) or the appropriate operator `char` (/, *, +, -) they would be stuck on that step till they got it right or otherwise closed the app entirely.

So one thing I got from the last question about this is that I could make a `boolean` value called "restart" or something and encapsulate my entire code except for the `main` `method` obviously and at the end I could make a question that they could answer `true` or `false` and the entire app could run again. While I admit having a "start over" button on my app is cool and useful for all my other a projects (probably not, I'm sure this can be done more efficiently), It still didn't satiate me and my original problem.

SO...

I got to trying everything I could (I know stack likes people who show that they at least tried).

EXAMPLE 1

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double valX;
        
            System.out.println("Calculator Activated.");

                do
                {
                    System.out.print("Value X: ");
                    valX = input.nextDouble();
                }while (!input.hasNextDouble());
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number!");
                }
//Didn't work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double valX;

            System.out.println("Calculator Activated.");

            while (!input.hasNextDouble())
            {
                System.out.println("Value X: ");
                valX = input.nextDouble();
            }
//neither this one...
```

Note that the solution you guys give me has to apply to every step of the program.

And for a bit more clarity is the entire src code without the stuff I tried and the "restart" loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double valX, valY, divided, multiplied, added, subtracted;  //Declared all my variables...
        char operator;
        boolean restart; //Didn't need to declare it true or false since I'm using a Scanner anyway

        do //Start of the entire program
        {
            System.out.println("Calculator Activated.");

            System.out.print("Value X: "); //I need a loop here...
            valX = input.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.print("Operator: "); //And here...
            operator = input.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.print("Value Y: "); //And here too..
            valY = input.nextDouble();

            divided = valX / valY;
            multiplied = valX * valY;
            added = valX + valY;
            subtracted = valX - valY;

            if (operator == '/')
                System.out.println("Result: " + divided );
            else if (operator == '*')
                System.out.println("Result: " + multiplied); //<--Not sure if I need a loop with the if's
            else if (operator == '+')
                System.out.println("Result: " + added);
            else if (operator == '-')
                System.out.println("Result: " + subtracted);
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid operator!");

            System.out.print("Try again? "); //I also need a loop here, I think.
            restart = input.nextBoolean();

        } while (restart); //End of it if you declared false.
        
        System.out.println("Calculator terminated.");
    }
}
```

At one point I tried to use the same "restart the app" concept and made a boolean variable for every single step in the code and it honestly was tiresome and not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final code example in the class called `CalTest` where you assign `valX = input.nextDouble();` you could a call recursive method that handles the exception until the input is what you want. Something like this:

```
private static double getNextDouble(Scanner input) {
    try {
        return input.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Value X must be a number: ");
        input.next();
        return getNextDouble(input);
    }
}
```

You'll replace `valX = input.nextDouble();` with `valX = getNextDouble(input);`.

You can tidy this up and make it work for your other potential error cases, perhaps creating a parameter for the output message and passing it in as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double valX=0,valY=0;
    char operator='0';//dummy default

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Calculator Activated.");

    Double dX = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Value X: ");
        dX = getDouble(input.next());
    }while (dX==null);
    {
        valX = dX;
    }

    Character op = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Operator: ");
        op = getOperator(input.next());
    }while (op==null);
    {
        operator=op;
    }


    Double dY = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Value Y: ");
        dY = getDouble(input.next());
    }while (dY==null);
    {
        valY = dY;
    }


    System.out.println("Done: "+ valX + " "+operator + " " +valY);
}

static Double getDouble(String input) {
    Double d = null;
    try {
        d = new Double(input);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    }
    return d;
}

static Character getOperator(String input) {
    Character c = null;
    if("+".equals(input) || "-".equals(input) || "*".equals(input) || "/".equals(input)){
        c = input.charAt(0);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Done: "+ valX + " "+operator + " " +valY);` - this just prints the x value, the operator and the y value. It doesn't print the output of the calc. Also `public Double(String s) throws NumberFormatException` is `@Deprecated(since="9")`.

Comment: @RobertBain 1> The question was not how to evaluate the expression, it was about how to validate user input in a loop, until he gets what is expected
2> Accepted. (my project is still on Java 8 and my IDE didnt show warning :))

Comment: Fair shout, I feel the catch block `catch(NumberFormatException ex)` that swallows the exception is a bit of a code smell too though. And the way we're boxing a primitive etc.

Comment: Indeed this is not production ready, hope the user does the "tidying up" :)